# How to create a public link for library in files?

Tags: contentdocument, urlhacking, content, contentworkspace

I Have a library let's say "XYZ Library" in Libraries Section of files and I need to get a public link for that library same as we create for Folders from the drop down, so that I can use it in a custom button to land in that Library.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't generate public link for a library. As a workaround, you can create a root folder inside the library and keep all files inside that folder. And generate public link for that folder.

Comment: Not sure, why there is a downvote for the answer. Please share your answer, if you have a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

The have the ability to create Public Link for folders within a Library, look at this help article from Salesforce. It explains the steps to take (involve going into Classic): https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000391143&type=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/193792)